# Are time complexities such as O(n/log n), O(n^2/log n) rarely seen in practice?

Tags: big-o, time-complexity

It is very common to see algorithms with time complexity `O(n), O(n*log n), O(2n)`, etc. Are there any algorithm in practice that bears the time complexities like `O(n/log n), O(2^n/P(n))` (where `P(n)` is a polynomial of n)? If so, can anyone please give an example? If not, why are these time complexities uncommonly seen in practice? Thank you.

Comment: Complexities tend to multiply.

Comment: Anything less than O(n), such as O(n/log n) means that only part of the input needs to be read in order to answer the problem. Most interesting problems require reading at least a constant fraction of the input to be answered.

Comment: This is a theoretical question, not a programming problem. Try http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @PascalCuoq You're right, I should have removed O(n/log n) from my question.

Comment: Just found one in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations#cite_ref-7 , wondering if there are more examples

Comment: O(n/logn) is bigger than O(logn) and i think there a some O(logn) algorithms, a famous one would be binary search :)

Comment: I think a reason why you commonly see O(n) or O(n*logn) is, that this can often be proven easyly. If you calculate the exact steps, that an algorithm take, you will often get something ugly and in most cases you will not get a solution. Calculating the complexity of an algorithm in general is very hard.

Comment: @AbcAeffchen Thank you for your comment. It is helpful. Moreover I have found some more complicated examples in which the complexity is the inverse of the Ackermann's function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do actually see runtimes like O(n<sup>2</sup> / log n) in practice in a few circumstances. There's a family of techniques often referred to as the "[Method of Four Russians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_Four_Russians)" that can be used to speed up certain types of algorithms. Typically, the Four Russians trick speeds up an algorithm by brute-force computing the solution to the problem on all inputs of size Θ(log n), then reframing the original input of size n or n<sup>2</sup> as a group of O(n / log n) or O(n<sup>2</sup> / log n) blocks, each of which is a subproblem of size Θ(log n). The runtime of these algorithms is then usually some polynomial over some polylogarithmic term, where the polylogarithmic speedup comes from the fact that the original problem size has been shrunk down by a polylogarithmic factor.

For example, the standard DP algorithm for computing the edit distance of two strings of length n runs in time O(n<sup>2</sup>). Using a Four-Russians-style speedup, this can be improved to [O(n<sup>2</sup> / log<sup>2</sup> n)](http://users-cs.au.dk/cstorm/courses/AiBS_e13/papers/Gusfield97_FourRussians.pdf). Multiplying boolean matrices typically takes time O(n<sup>3</sup>), which can be improved to O(n<sup>3</sup> / log n) using the original Four-Russians trick.

You can imagine similar tricks that could give you runtimes like O(2<sup>n</sup> / poly(n)) - just try using algorithms like the above ones on inputs where the input is exponentially large.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I know it has been quite a long time, but I have found that it helps a lot and thanks for your answer.